# how to get data from DB using axios

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js, controller

I’m having a problem.

i have list of project i want when i click in one project he take me to another page(components) this is the component ProjectDetail when i can find the detail of that project  Inside of it, I have this block of code:
this is the route who take me to another components:

```
 {path: '/detail/:id', name: detail , component: detail },
```

I want to get the project with the id in the url detail from DB w but nothing Happen this is ProjectDetail.vue:

```
export default {
      data(){
      return{
      id: this.$route.params.id,
    projets:[],
   projet:{
    id:'',
   name:'',
     durre:'',
  description:'',
      budget:'',
  owner:'',
      }
   }
 },
      methods:{ 
    afficherProjets(){
       axios.get('api/getProjects/'+this.id)
         .then(data => {
           this.projets = data.data;
               });
                  }
           },
          mounted() {
           console.log('Component mounted.')
           this.afficherProjets();
        }
           }
```

and this is my controller:

```
 public function getProjects($id)
{
   return Projet::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked in your browser dev tools for any JavaScript errors in the console or any errors in the HTTP response that you get back from your API?

Comment: there is no errors and he show projects:undefined  in dev tools

Comment: you should replace `{data}` with `response` and console.log it. My guess is, you should use `this.project = data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your vue.

```
export default {
  data(){
   return{
    id: this.$route.params.id,
    projet:{}
  }
},
methods:{
 //GETID
 afficherProjet(){
   axios.get('api/getProject/'+this.id)
      .then(data => {
              this.projet = data.data;
           });
 }
},
mounted() {
  console.log('Component mounted.')
  this.afficherProjet();
}
```

File in routes api.php

```
//ALL
Route::get('getProjects', ['uses' =>'API\ProjetController@getProjects']);
//SPECIFIQ ID
Route::get('getProject/{id}', ['uses' =>'API\ProjetController@getProject']);
```

In your controller, app/Http/API/ProjetController

```
public function getProjects()
{
   return Projet::latest()->paginate(15);
}

public function getProject($id)
{
  return Projet::findOrFail($id);
}
```

Your model projet

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projet extends Model
{
   public $timestamps = false;

   protected $table = 'projets';

   protected $fillable = [
     'name',
     'durre',
     'description',
     'budget',
     'owner'
   ];
}
```

Do you have your model?

Your error comes from the 'data.data' i thing it's empty, you should just call 'data'.

Personally i prefer Mounted.

I thing now it's working!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208842/discussion-on-answer-by-snoxik-how-to-get-data-from-db-using-axios).